# In Java, which constructor will be chosen when parameter is null

Tags: java, oop, null, overloading, constructor-overloading

Let's say I have this code:

```
public class A{
    public A(String b){}
    public A(Cursor c){}
    public A(SomeClass n){}
}
```

Now I want to create an instance of `A` but I don't know which constructor will select when the only parameter is `null`:

```
A someA = new A(null);
```

How should I manage this and figure it out ?

**UPDATE**

I have test this, it wont be compile with `null` but when I use a null object it will consider what is type of object like:

```
String n = null;
A someA = new A(n);
```

it will execute `public A(String b){}`

Is that safe ?

Comment: Try it out and see what the compiler says.

Comment: It won't pass compilation.

Comment: What about avoidining passing null altogether? This looks like a XY problem so why don't you explain what you want to do first?

Comment: consider that is exactly what I want to compile, it's a big problem.

Comment: Have you read the duplicate?  The accepted answer perfectly answers this and your new question.

Comment: @Makoto is my code Safe?

Answer (score 0):

It ll result in compilation error, as the method call is `ambiguous`.